# Pivot item show below Pivot Item content

Tags: uwp

Is there anyway, I could put Pivot content (pivot item) above the actual pivot. So I mean that the content is at the bottom or side?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I found was to edit the template and them change it inside to position stuff as I want.